# MySQL stored procedure `EXECUTE` command with user defined variable rather than input parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL which is not supposed to be vulnerable to SQL injection. Hence I am using prepared statements inside this. I have a `Patient` table to which I want to add data using this procedure. This is what my stored procedure looks like.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreatePatient;
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePatient (IN alias VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

PREPARE q1 FROM 'insert into Patient values (?)';

set @alias = alias;

EXECUTE q1 USING @alias;

END @@
DELIMITER ;
```

When I tried to run this without setting a new variable `@alias`,

```
EXECUTE q1 USING alias;
```

I am getting an SQL syntax error. From my understanding, it doesn't seem right to create a variable within the method body just to assign it the input variable to the procedure. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has 3 types of variables

- User Defined Variables
- Local variables
- session variables

User defined variables have session scope while local variables have a block scope i.e within **BEGIN-END** Block.

> Because local variables are in scope only during stored program execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements created within a stored program. Prepared statement scope is the current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no longer be in scope. For example, SELECT ... INTO local_var cannot be used as a prepared statement. This restriction also applies to stored procedure and function parameters

[See official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html)